# Laravel - File Upload Validation issue

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel

I'm dealing with a file upload in Laravel.  The actual upload is fine, but I'm trying to do some basic validation and am getting odd results.  For starters, I'm trying to make sure the user uploads SOMETHING.  So in the POST method, I have:

```
$rules = array(
            'video' => 'required',
        );

        $messages = array(
            'required' => 'Please upload a video',
        );

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validation->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::route('candidateJobPreinterview', $job)
                ->withErrors($validation)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

However, when I submit a form (with no upload), I get a Laravel error: "Array to string conversion".  This seems to be occurring not during the validation itself, but rather, when I try to redirect to the original route with `->withErrors($validation)`

any idea why?

EDIT: My mistake, the error seems to occur at `if ($validation->fails())`

Comment: Maybe with `->withErrors($validation->messages())`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion that didn't seem to change anything